# Micronaut 1.3.5: Page not found

Tags: java, micronaut

GET http://localhost:8080/system/version

GET http://localhost:8080/system/version/

```
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;

@Controller("/system")
public class SystemController {
    @Get(uri = "/version/")
    public String version() {
        return SystemController.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    }
}
```

leads to

```
{
"message": "Page Not Found",
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "/system/version/",
        "templated": false
    }
}
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I believe this is working as designed.  See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a controller method like that returns `null`, that will result in a 404. I expect that `SystemController.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` is evaluating to `null`.